FastAPI return an empty SQLAlchemy in response
I have this function and others similars (with the same problem):
async def update_row_by_id(db: Session, tableOrm, tableModel, object_id:int):
    obj_update = fetch_object_by_id(db, tableOrm, object_id)
    for field in tableModel.model_dump(exclude_unset=True):
        setattr(obj_update, field, getattr(tableModel, field))

    try:
        if(obj_update.updated_by is None):
            obj_update.updated_by = db.query(literal_column("current_user"))
        obj_update.updated_at = datetime.now()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        db.commit()
    except (ProgrammingError,IntegrityError, PendingRollbackError) as e:
        db.rollback()
        print(e._message())
        raise HTTPException(status_code = status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, detail = e._message())
    return obj_update

It's called like this:
    @router.put(urlIdRoute, status_code=200)
    async def crud_update_by_id(obj_id:int, obj_model:modelBase):
        db = SessionLocal()
        try:
            res = await update_row_by_id(db, orm, obj_model, obj_id)
            return res
        finally:
            db.close()

The problem is, in fastapi/docs, when I test this endpoint, it returns {}, but the data is commited in database.
The other problem/solution is: If I put a print(obj_update) BEFORE return statement, the endpoint returns the data correctly.
Why is my code being affected by print statement and how can I fix this without need to put print(obj_update)?
I tried to create async/await on fetching data, but other errors appears, here is the object_fetch function:
def fetch_object_by_id(db: Session, tableOrm, object_id:int):
    obj = db.scalar(select(tableOrm).filter_by(id = object_id))
    if obj is None:
        raise common_404_exception(tableOrm.__tablename__, object_id)
    return obj


Your fetch_object_by_id needs to handle the database call using async/ await
async def fetch_object_by_id(db: Session, tableOrm, object_id:int):
    obj = await db.scalar(select(tableOrm).filter_by(id = object_id))
    if obj is None:
        raise common_404_exception(tableOrm.__tablename__, object_id)
    return obj

Then in your route use obj_update = await fetch_object_by_id(db, tableOrm, object_id)
